# Wildcard character not working in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When i execute the following snippet of code, df1 shows no result. When i substitute the wild character "*" with a "1,2,3,.." df1 shows values. What am i missing?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import pyspark.sql.functions
.
.
.
df1= df.filter(df.DATE == "*162014").filter(df.TMC == "111N04908")\
       .sort(df.EPOCH.asc())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only that `==` means it equals - nothing more, nothing less. It doesn't use wildcards, regular expressions or SQL patterns. If you want to use patterns use [`LIKE`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.like) or [`RLIKE`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike).

```
expr("DATE RLIKE '%162014'")
expr("DATE LIKE '*162014'")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```py
df1 = df.filter(df.DATE.rlike('*162014'))
        .filter(df.TMC == "111N04908")
        .sort(df.EPOCH.asc())
```

where or filter both are same

```py
df1 = df.where(df.DATE.rlike('*162014'))
        .where(df.TMC == "111N04908")
        .sort(df.EPOCH.asc())
```